# Documentation on Play 2 Stand Alone Template Engine

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Ive heard and read that play 2 has a stand-alone template engine. I'm having trouble though finding any documentation to explain how to go about using it.  Could someone point me in the direction of finding something to show me how to go about using it as a stand-alone and not in the framework?

Comment: I doubt if you'll find any documentation about that, here, you'll find just some tips: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/BD70wnmF0fo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/spray/twirl

There's this, which the spray.io guys copy/pasta'd out of Play 2 for use in applications architected on the various spray.io components.

Answer (score 2):

The Twirl has been moved back to Play, so you might want to checkout https://github.com/playframework/twirl